# i'm getting a blank sql file after running this code. :(

Tags: java, mysql

```
private void jMenuItem16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  
{                                            

    int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Backup ??" , "Backup" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(r==0){
        String filename = BackupNamer.getname();

        try{

            Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C path=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin;mysqldump -uroot --password=12345 librarysystem>D:\\"+filename+"");


         int pr = rt.waitFor();
         if(pr==0){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "backup created");
         }
         else if(pr==1){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
         }



        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

through this code i wanted to create a backup of my database.but it only creates an empty file in the given path.

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is your call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`: It expects *separate* strings for the program and all arguments. For example:

```
Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe", "/C", "path=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin;mysqldump", "-uroot", "--password=12345", "librarysystem>D:\\"+filename);
```